# Zend_Navigation and module specific layout

Tags: zend-framework, module, bootstrapping, zend-navigation

I am developing a web site using the Zend Framework.
I was using this site to get my navigation working: http://www.rvdavid.net/zend_navigation-makes-writing-navigation-for-zf-sites-very-easy/.

However, the $this->layout()->menu returns NULL.
I have a modular structure, with a plugin that takes care of module specific layout:

```
<?php
class Custom_Controller_Plugin_ModuleBasedLayout 
    extends Zend_Layout_Controller_Plugin_Layout
{
public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
{
        $this->getLayout()->setLayoutPath(Zend_Registry::get('config')->resources->frontController->moduleDirectory
        . DS . $request->getModuleName() . DS . 'layouts' );
}
}
```

Does anybody have a clue why my navigation isn't working?

Comment: It should be $this->layout()->menu(). Menu is a method, not a property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its `$this->navigation()->menu();`

not `$this->layout()->menu`

all the rendering stuff of Zend_Navigation is done by navigation  view helper which you use in  `*.phtml files`